# Replace SQLite database with a MySQL Database in Django

Tags: mysql, django

I am currently working on my first Django project. I made a website where my team and I could upload CSV's to be run through python and I made a SQLite model that I never really used.

I now have access to this website's database so we no longer have to use these CSVs downloaded from the site. I have been trying to follow along online on how to switch to an existing database. The database is managed through phpMyAdmin and uses MySql

First I updated my database config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'MadeUpName',
        'USER': 'UserIDForDB',
        'PASSWORD': 'MyPasswordThatGoesWithUser',
        'HOST': 'db.Website.com',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

For clarification, for Name I just made up a name, User and Password are my login credentials for PHPMyAdmin, the Host is the actual host I was told I could use when connecting through code and I left port blank for defaults.

I removed the old model I had built in the models.py file.

When I run  python manage.py inspectdb I still see the model I build and my admin/user stuff.

I have tried migrating but it says no migrations. I also made sure to install mysql.

I imagine I am missing a step or am mistaken on how the databases should go.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove PORT from the dict to use the default, second make sure that MySQL is listening on 3306 on all interfaces so you can connect from other node. Lastly, run ‘python manage.py dbshell’ and check which shell are you getting sqlite or mysql.

Comment: I removed port. I am not sure what you mean by " second make sure that MySQL is listening on 3306 on all interfaces so you can connect from other node", I am still getting sqlite when I run that

Comment: Is there any other DATABASES in your settings file.

Comment: It seems I had changed the Project settings, but not the app. I changed the app and now I am getting "CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path."  but I did install mysql